# Is publishing the URL of a free eBook pernissbale (if requeste dby another user)?

Tags: discussion

Please take a look at @EstherSchindler answer to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125516/what-are-the-common-employer-worries-screeners-when-selecting-remote-developers/126009?noredirect=1#comment401210_126009).

Is there any reason why she should not post the URL to her eBook? I for one would like to read it, if she is agreeable, and I think that it would help others. I can see no harm in doing so ...

Answer (score 4):

Here are some relevant links:

From the accepted [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/377968) to "How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?"

> - you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
> - you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
> - **someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all**
> - you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile

The FAQ on [What makes something spam and when should I flag it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/377968)

> A post should be marked as spam only if it **advertises** a product, service, or similar **and is unsolicited *or* lacks disclosure**.

And, since Esther discloses her affiliation, I just quote the part about *Unsolicited*:

> - *Unsolicited* means that mentioning the product serves no purpose other than promotion. For example, if an answer mentions a software that may solve the asker’s problem or a question about web programming references a website as an example, this is not unsolicited (it may still be spam if there is an undisclosed affiliation).

In addition, here is a relevant [answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4345/75187) from TWP Meta itself.

If the answer meets these requirements after the link was included, it would be okay.

Comment: Well, it looks fine to me, but I am biased because I would like to see it :-) What do you think?

Comment: As mod elsewhere, I think the author has done the right thing, the answer already stands on its own without the link, and it would be enhanced with the link. I would not class this as spam

Comment: @Mawg I didn't include my own opinion, because I'm just a low-rep user and it doesn't matter much (especially considering how many users TWP has). Did you already try googling "esther schindler o'reilly"?